# Stop GUI when logging in as a specific user in Lubuntu 20.04 (LXQt)

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, lubuntu, login, lxqt

I have a very limited and rusty knowledge of Lubuntu, and it is my first post here - so please bear with me if the question is obvious, if I break any etiquette rules, or if I am simply not providing enough info.

I need to set up a user session that starts in command line and then into a VirtualBox VM. I should have the second part covered by creating an ad-hoc entry in `/usr/share/xsessions/`, but I can't figure out how to automatically stop LXQt at login.

So far, all the information I can seem to find are about disabling LXQt at boot - but that is not what I am after, since I want the greeter and the GUI to load for all other sessions.

Thank you!

Comment: If you boot a Lubuntu system (*assuming auto-login isn't enabled*), your system will boot to the greeter which is `sddm` for Lubuntu.  No LXQt is running at this point, which you can confirm by switching to text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4) and logging in, then `ps -elf |grep lxqt` etc).  The LXQt/Lubuntu-session doesn't start until a user logs in at `sddm` so the LXQt session is optional; if you look Lubuntu already allows you to not use LXQt but login using only `openbox` or the WM used by Lubuntu.  LXQt isn't started until a user selects it at login (2 of the 3 default options allow LXQt)

Comment: If you look top left in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0vni.jpg you'll see the Session box that allows users to pick a session. Your settings can have this default to Lubuntu (*what it is for a new install*) through to whatever was used last, meaning once changed to a non-LXQt session (eg. the `openbox` WM only I mentioned last comment Lubuntu provides by default) the user will login next time with that session, unless the user opts to force it to a specific session choice.  Lubuntu offers *Lubuntu* (all our tweaks), *LXQt* (closer to upstream default) or *Openbox* (WM only; no LXQt)